# Verify data with Signature public key RSA java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

I have simple text.

Then i encrypt this text with `Cipher` RSA.

But when verify this text with encrypt text by `Signature` it always return false.

Generate key pair:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Plain text:

```
byte[] plaintext = "a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Encrypt text using RSA:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kp.getPublic());
byte[] encryptText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
```

Verify data using `Signature`:

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initVerify(kp.getPublic());
sig.update(plaintext);
boolean result = sig.verify(encryptText);
System.out.println(result);
```

Why this code always return `false`? How to verify right way?

Comment: The counterpart to encryption is not verification but decryption. And the counterpart to verification is not encryption but signing, which is why your verification fails. Encryption and decryption on the one hand and signing and verifying on the other use different paddings.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point. Please give me more explanation, about my code @Topaco

Comment: Encrypting/decrypting and signing/verifying are different things. You can use [`Signature#verify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte%5B%5D)) to verify a signature created with [`Signature#sign()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Signature.html#sign()).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. i understand now.

Answer (score 4):

In digital signature, you sign (encrypt) the hash of the data using your **private** key.

You could use Signature class, it will handle the hasing of the data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String message = "Digital Signature Example";
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes("UTF8");

    // Key generation
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

    // sign
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    sig.initSign(key.getPrivate());
    sig.update(messageBytes);
    byte[] signature = sig.sign();

    // verification
    sig.initVerify(key.getPublic());
    sig.update(messageBytes);
    boolean result = sig.verify(signature);

    // result
    System.out.println("Message   = " + message);
    System.out.println("Signature = "
            + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature));
    System.out.println("Verification Result = " + result);
}
```

Or you could encrypt/decrypt by using cipher class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String message = "Digital Signature Example";
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes("UTF8");

    // Key generation
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

    // sign
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key.getPrivate());
    byte[] messageHash = SHA(message);
    byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal(messageHash);
    
    // verification
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key.getPublic());
    byte[] decryptedMessageHash = cipher.doFinal(signature);
    byte[] messageHash = SHA(message);
    boolean result = Arrays.equals(decryptedMessageHash, messageHash);

    System.out.println("Message   = " + message);
    System.out.println("Signature = "
            + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature));
    System.out.println("Verification Result = " + result);
}


private static byte[] SHA(String message) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    digest.update(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
    return digest.digest();
}
```